# Why do I get missing SELECT keyword error

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm just started with SQL and I have couple of lines of code

```
INSERT All INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID)
VALUES 
('V01', 'WILSON', 'SARAH', 'DR', '6122', 'SENIOR PARTNER', '45,000', P1)
INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID)
('V02', 'MCDONALD', 'BRYAN', 'DR', '6153', 'SENIOR PARTNER', '35,000', P1)
INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID)
('V03', 'PATEL', 'JANE', 'DR', '6165', 'JUNIOR PARTNER', '29,000', P2)
INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID)
('V04', 'MCCAFFERTY', 'TREVOR', 'MR', '6166', 'JUNIOR PARTNER', '25,600', P2)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

and I'm getting `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword` error not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You missed `VALUES` keyword in some statements, it's would be like below:

```
    INSERT All 
        INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID) VALUES ('V01', 'WILSON', 'SARAH', 'DR', '6122', 'SENIOR PARTNER', '45,000', P1) 
        INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID) VALUES ('V02', 'MCDONALD', 'BRYAN', 'DR', '6153', 'SENIOR PARTNER', '35,000', P1) 
        INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID) VALUES ('V03', 'PATEL', 'JANE', 'DR', '6165', 'JUNIOR PARTNER', '29,000', P2) 
        INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID) VALUES ('V04', 'MCCAFFERTY', 'TREVOR', 'MR', '6166', 'JUNIOR PARTNER', '25,600', P2) 
        SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Farshid said you are missing `Values` on some of your statements,
but you can also further simplify the statement by only comma separating your value list, instead of having a bunch of insert statements

```
INSERT INTO VET (VET_ID, SURNAME, FORENAME, TITLE, EXT_NUMBER, POSITION, SALARY, PRACTICE_ID)
VALUES 
('V01', 'WILSON', 'SARAH', 'DR', '6122', 'SENIOR PARTNER', '45,000', P1),
('V02', 'MCDONALD', 'BRYAN', 'DR', '6153', 'SENIOR PARTNER', '35,000', P1),
('V03', 'PATEL', 'JANE', 'DR', '6165', 'JUNIOR PARTNER', '29,000', P2),
('V04', 'MCCAFFERTY', 'TREVOR', 'MR', '6166', 'JUNIOR PARTNER', '25,600', P2)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Comment: Oracle does not support this.